# adding a table layout in linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am trying to add a table inside a linear layout. Inside my linear layout there is `textview`, `spinner`. When I try to add a table layout it doesn't align correctly. Below is my code

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/cardLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Product"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:layout_margin="10sp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/product_spinner"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        />


                </LinearLayout>

                <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    >
                    <TableRow android:background="#0079D6" android:padding="5dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Product Name" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Sale" />
                    </TableRow>
                    <TableRow android:background="#DAE8FC" android:padding="5dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

I must be missing something that I don't know. How  can I align them equally just  like in the above image

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: if you're new to android development, i'd suggest not wasting time with LinearLayout, just learn constraint layout

Comment: Such a nest set of Linear Layout will be very slow, much better to use a constraint layout and a recyclerview in place of the Table Layout

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

```
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Product"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/product_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            >
            <TableRow android:background="#0079D6" android:padding="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Product Name" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Sale" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:background="#DAE8FC" android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```